# Почему не компилится код в cmd, а в idea норм?

Tags: java, cmd

Прога срабатывает нормально, но как только я добавляю зависимость в мавен и реализую эту библиотеку - error в cmd, то же самое происходит, когда просто код из main класса переношу в отдельный:

```
C:\Users\phil\Desktop>java c:\Users\phil\MyProjects\Archiver\src\main\java\Main.java
c:\Users\phil\MyProjects\Archiver\src\main\java\Main.java:2: error: package org.apache.tika 
does not exist
import org.apache.tika.Tika;
          ^
c:\Users\phil\MyProjects\Archiver\src\main\java\Main.java:3: error: package 
org.apache.tika.exception does not exist
import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
                    ^
 c:\Users\phil\MyProjects\Archiver\src\main\java\Main.java:4: error: package 
org.apache.tika.metadata does not exist
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
                   ^
c:\Users\phil\MyProjects\Archiver\src\main\java\Main.java:144: error: cannot find symbol
 public static Metadata extractMetadatatUsingFacade(InputStream stream)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Компилирование классов осуществляется командой

```
javac
```

а запуск откомпилированных приложений командой

```
java
```

Comment: все равно, я это пробовал           C:\Users\phil\Desktop>javac c:\Users\phil\MyProjects\Archiver\src\main\java\Main.java
c:\Users\phil\MyProjects\Archiver\src\main\java\Main.java:2: error: package org.apache.tika does not exist
import org.apache.tika.Tika;
                      ^
c:\Users\phil\MyProjects\Archiver\src\main\java\Main.java:3: error: package org.apache.tika.exception does not exist
import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
                                ^

Comment: при том что в идее норм

Comment: Внимательно читай инструкцию к компилятору! Там надо указывать все пути ко всем дополнительными библиотекам. Сам по себе компилятор не знает где их искать. Когда ide компилирует проект она все эти опции за тебя проставляет, когда сам компилируешь - это уже твоя задача. Тебе нужна документация по javac